# Pushing Data from server to client on request without closing connection?

Tags: java, http, tomcat, servlets, comet

My Goal to getting data from server at every 3sec.

So, to keep overhead as minimum as possible i am trying to not to open new connection and sending request.

So, I am trying to implementing servlet to push data from server to client with only once client request to server. For that , I try to use comet pattern but given link of code is not working for me. I am using Tomcat server. I am using HttpClient API for client code to prints data to file.

Also tried this code but it is not working for me,

http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-03-2008/jw-03-asynchhttp-test.html?page=6

If i understand something wrong please correct me.And If possible to do this any better way than please suggest me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry i am not from the Java background, but i think Client-Server Model remains same independent of the technology.
HTML 5 Web Sockets or HTML5 Server Side Push(SSE - Server Sent Events) are the best and latest things nowadays

You can refer:

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/websockets/basics/
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/html5_websocket.htm

Comment: Yes, WebSocket  works from tomcat 7.0.27 and upto.But, has some issue with proxy . here is demo https://gist.github.com/chitan/3063774    So, I used Async behavior of servlet 3.0 to do that
for some time delay and and created HttpClient.
Thank you